# how to know tweening of objects got finished in createjs

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am converting flash to html5 files using createjs; in our flash we are having 5 scenes. After completing one scene we have to load the other scene.

For each scene we have one js file. For the first scene I am loading the first js file; for the second scene I have to load the second js file. I am unable to know when the first is going to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just call a function when the tween is complete?

```
var tween = new cretejs.Tween();
tween.get( target).to({x: some_x}).call( onTweenComplete);

function onTweenComplete(){

//Tween is done
}
```